# Difference between 'mulcted with' and 'mulcted of'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, prepositional-verbs

Mulct means ( mulct something of ) - Take money or possession from (someone) by fraudulent means.

In this context, preposition " of " is understandable with this word.

Example : *Before he left for the north, Henry mulcted the citizens of 500 marks.*

But today i read a new usage that is 'mulcted with' . There are some sentences in the same context

1.*The petitioner was greatly prejudiced as she had been mulcted with these proceedings out of political rivalry.*

2.*For example, if an employee is involved in embezzlement of funds or is found indulging in demanding and accepting illegal gratification, the employer cannot be mulcted with full back wages on the acquittal of the person by a criminal court, unless it is found that the prosecution is malicious,” a Bench of Justices L. Nageswara Rao and M.R. Shah observed in a recent verdict.*

Can you please clarify these two sentences to me. In the first sentence, I am thinking that mulcted with means deceived with. Second one is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mulct means "fine or tax or punish" (both as a noun and a verb), though it is sometimes used to mean "swindle", this is an extended sense, from the notion of an unfair fine or tax.

It is also *rare* and *formal*, enough so that I needed a dictionary to understand the word.

Insofar as there is a "usual" use with such a rare word,  "The Judge mulcted Joe of £500" is typical.  But as your examples show "mulcted with" is possible.

In your first example, the petition is apparently being punished with court proceedings.  Here mulcted means "punished", not "swindled". It is a slight variation, as mulcted usually refers to financial punishments.

In the second, mulcted appears to mean "punish" the employer by having to pay back-wages to a person acquitted of embezzlement.   But it is very hard to understand (if the person was acquitted, then it follows that legally they were not involved in embezzlement, which sets up a contradiction).

The conclusion is that when mulcted is used to mean "punished" we can use "mulcted with".  Though the word is so rare that it would nearly always be clearer to use "fined", "taxed", or "punished" as appropriate.

Comment: ..does it mean that in 'mulcted with' with is used because it is used in different way. That is generally mulct means money fine but here it means that proceedings are punishment and in the second sentence same is the case.